# Issue in Building Gradle file in Android Studio

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dependencies, execution

my gradle file contains :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shiponk"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

When I am Using below dependencies for PayUBiz integration in my Application.

```
compile 'com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:6.0.0'//this is gradle path from where CB will be automatically downloaded
compile 'com.payu.magicretry:magicretry:1.0.4'
```

getting below error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/jaimin/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: try clean and then rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

You should change your target sdk version.

like this.

- targetSdkVersion 23

and if still problem remove

"multidex" from default config.

Comment: I have set it to 20 ... because Notification icon issue.. If it 23 then the appicon in notification bar going to be strached(or changed.-not proper).

Comment: Hey, I have done it to 23 . but, still error displaying.